# What speed will result in the lowest fuel cost for the trip? What is the lowest total fuel cost for the trip?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> A truck traveling at $x$ km/h, where $30\le x \le 120$, uses gasoline at a rate of $r(x)\text{L}/100$ km, where $r(x)=(1/400)(4900/x + x)$. If fuel costs $\$ 1.15/$L, What speed will result in the lowest fuel cost for the trip? What is the lowest total fuel cost for the trip?

I already took the derivative of the equation and found out the speed that results in the lowest fuel cost is $70$km/h. Yet, I am having trouble understanding how to get the lowest total fuel cost for the trip.

Comment: Now that you know the optimal value of $x$, put that back into $r(x)$ to find minimum fuel usage. Then multiply by cost to find minimum fuel cost.

Answer (score 0):

If $70\frac{km}{hr}$ really is the optimum (make sure you check endpoints of the interval $[30,120])$!

Then you just want to find out how much fuel is used or for distance travelled $d$ (not given in your post), 
$$
r(70)\frac{L}{100 \;km}*d\;km=r(70)*d\;\text{Liters}
$$
Multiplying the above quantity of liters used on your trip of length $d$ by the cost of fuel per liter, gives you your final answer:
$$
r(70)*d\;L*\frac{1.15\;\text{dollars}}{L}=r(70)*d*1.15\;\text{dollars}
$$